# Adding CSS class to navigation element dynamically in WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, menu

I have a WooCommerce site with the following Products permalink structure: `/products/shop/`

The client wants a custom "Product" page rather than the default generated one. The challenge is that the actual product pages don't trigger the navigation product link to have an active state.  I can't make it have the same active orange background color as the non WooCommerce pages within that group of pages.

Do you have any ideas on dynamically adding a class to the menu item when a product page is viewed so I can style the navigation element?

Link to development site:

- https://wordpress-1164757-4160273.cloudwaysapps.com/products/
- https://wordpress-1164757-4160273.cloudwaysapps.com/products/shop/bp-protease-003-1000/

Comment: You don't need to add any css class as WooCommerce single product pages have a body class "single-product"… So based on your provided single product link, try to add the following CSS rule: `.single-product #mega-menu-item-7520 > a.mega-menu-link { background: #f2682b; color: #fff; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; border-color: #fff; }`, it should work as you expect.

Comment: Yes, thanks!  I always forget about the body classes...  Worked perfectly.